# WPF binding to CurrentItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF model which contains a viewsource, a listview, and a button, which is meant to execute an ICommand in the viewmodel for the item selected in the listview.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="teachingSessionsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:TeachingSessionListItem}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
    <GroupBox Header="All Sessions" 
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource teachingSessionsViewSource}}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView x:Name="TeachingSessionList" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=/}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource noHeaderStyle}">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SessionDate}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PresenterInitials}" Width="30" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Button Content="Un-Assign" Margin="5,5" Command="{Binding Path=/UnAssignPresentation}" 
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

The problem is that the ICommand UnAssignPresentation is always executed on the first item in the list, regardless of which item is selected in the listview. That is to say, the currentItem property of the CollectionViewSource does not seem to be bound to the ListView.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` to your ListView.

Also, prefer binding listview to a collection in your view model and not to a resource.
You can then add a property to the view model for the selected item
and bind the listview's selected item to that property in the view model
and either bind the button's command to a command in the view model that acts on the current item,
or pass the item you want to act on via the command parameter binded to the selected item.